# Unable to build LLVM with BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON using MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, clang, mingw, llvm

When building LLVM in debug mode, the resulting clang and clang++ executables are > 2GB in size and cannot be run on Windows. In order to reduce the final executable size I have set the LLVM BUILD_SHARED_LIBS flag to ON in CMake however the build fails at 100% when linking clang++.exe in clangDynamicASTMatchers.dll with hundreds of 'undefined reference to `vtable for clang::ast_matchers...' errors.

The [LLVM CMake docs](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html) indicate that shared libraries can be used on Windows when building with MinGW, which I am, so I was wondering whether anyone has successfully built LLVM with this flag enabled on Windows?